# trying to get Angular 2 to wait for data(s) to load before rendering

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I have multiple XML files I need to load before the initial rendering. What I have is 
app.module.ts

```
import { DataProvider } from './xml-provider'

export function dataProviderFactory(provider: DataProvider) {
  return () => provider.load();
}

providers: [
    DataProvider,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: dataProviderFactory, deps: [DataProvider], multi: true }
  ],
```

then in xml-provider.ts

```
load(){
  let promises:Promise<any>[] = [];
  promises.push(this.loader1());
  promises.push(this.loader2());

  Promise.all(promises).then(
    (values) => { 
      console.log("Promise all finished: " + values);
      return true; 
    }
  );
}



  private loader1():Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('assets/data.xml')
        .map(res => {
          let data;
          parseString(res.text(), { trim: true } ,function (err, result) {
            data = result.xml;
          });
          this.xmldata = data;
        })
        .subscribe(data => { resolve(true); })
    })    
  }
```

When I had the loader1 as the load function, Angular did wait until the file was loaded and all was well.  Now that I have added more files, it's not waiting for load to return. What have I missed to make the app.module.ts wait until all files are loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `return` missing in front of `Promise.all`. I hope it fixes the problem.

```
load(){
  let promises:Promise<any>[] = [];
  promises.push(this.loader1());
  promises.push(this.loader2());

  //// Missing return was here
  return Promise.all(promises).then(
    (values) => { 
      console.log("Promise all finished: " + values);
      return true; 
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it!